# DRF, caching for as_view()?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-cache

In my view, I often use APIView's `as_view()` to generate json.

I'd like to cache the response and tried the following but it won't work

```
def some_complex_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    pass

@method_decorator(cache_page(60, key_prefix='drf'))
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then, I call

```
def my_view(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    json_data = MyViewSet.as_view({'get': 'some_complex_view'})(request, format='json')

    data = {
       'my_data': json_data
    }
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', data)
```

It correctly caches when I request the view using browser, but it won't when using `as_view()`

Comment: How do you construct the request when you directly call the view?

Comment: whats is your django version??

Comment: @knbk: I 'm in the django view function and it has the 'request'

Comment: @SathishKumarVG I use 1.9, willing to upgrade if needed.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, can you show the code?

Comment: @knbk: I updated the code to show the usage.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few strategies listed in the CBV docs:

Add the decorator in your urls.py route, e.g., `login_required(ViewSpaceIndex.as_view(..))`
Decorate your CBV's dispatch method with a `method_decorator` e.g.,

```
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class MyViewSet(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'secret.html'
```

Before Django 1.9 you can't use method_decorator on the class, so you have to override the dispatch method:

```
class MyViewSet(TemplateView):

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyViewSet, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: yes, it works when I request the url from the browser (network), but it won't if I call the view method directly with `as_view()`.